# Change position on Y axis based on distance

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to make a game where you're in a square and when you go to the sides, parts come up and block you.

I've gotten far to the point where it's working fine, except for a few problems:

the parts go below the square when not raised, I want them to be visible when they're not raised

the parts go down when you jump, making it easy to escape.

the parts go up too early

This is the code that deals with the wall positioning.

```
for _, v in pairs(model:GetChildren()) do
    if string.sub(v.Name,1,4) == "Wall" then
        local walls = {}
        walls[v] = {v.CFrame,Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)}
        game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:connect(function()
            if(workspace[game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name]:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")) then
                local mag = (v.Position - workspace[game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name]:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position).magnitude
                sizeFactor = math.floor(mag)
                v.CFrame = walls[v][1]*CFrame.new(0,-sizeFactor+(walls[v][1].Y*1.8),0)

            end
        end)    
    end
end
```

You can see my game here: https://www.roblox.com/games/400391033/Marble-walls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See commented code.

```
                for _, v in pairs(model:GetChildren()) do
                if string.sub(v.Name,1,4) == "Wall" then
                    local walls = {}
                    walls[v] = {v.CFrame,Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)}
                    game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:connect(function()
                        if(workspace[game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name]:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")) then
                            local mag = (v.Position - workspace[game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name]:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position).magnitude
                            if (mag <= 2) then --[[
                                    Currently your issue is that you never actually do ANYTHING regarding magnitude
                                    you essentially change the y-Axis as soon as the player spawns.. hence why it does it too early
                                    kappa
                                ]] 
                                sizeFactor = math.floor(mag)
                                v.CFrame = walls[v][1]*CFrame.new(0,-sizeFactor+(walls[v][1].Y*1.8),0)
                            end;
                        end
                    end)    
                end
            end
```